# getting the remainder and quotient in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

Could you please help of why this code is not working?

```
.MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 64 
.DATA

INPUT DB 13, 10, "Enter input : ","$" 
OPERAND DB 13,10, "ENTER OPERAND:,  
SUM DB 13,10, "The sum is : ","$" 
DIFF DB 13,10, "The difference is : ","$" 
MULTI DB 13,10, "The product is : ","$" 
DIVI DB 13,10, "The quotient is : ","$" 
MODULO DB 13,10, "The modulo is : ","$" 
NUM1 db ? 
NUM2 db ? 
OP db ? 
RES db ?

;-----------------------------------------------------

.CODE 
MAIN PROC NEAR

    MOV AX, @DATA 
    MOV DS, AX

    ; outputs "input" message 
    LEA DX, INPUT 
    MOV AH, 09h 
    INT 21h

    ; get first input 
    MOV AH, 01h 
    INT 21h 
    SUB AL, 0 
    MOV NUM1, AL

    ; get operand 
    MOV AH, 01h 
    INT 21h 
    MOV OP, AL

    ; get second input 
    MOV AH, 01h 
    INT 21h 
    SUB AL, 0 
    MOV NUM2, AL

    CMP OP, "+" 
    JE  @ADD

    CMP OP, "-" 
    JE  @SUB

    CMP OP, "*" 
    JE  @MULTIPLY

    CMP OP, "/" 
    JE  @DIVIDE

    CMP OP, "%" 
    JE  @MOD

@ADD : 
    ADD AL, NUM1 
    MOV RES, AL

    LEA DX, SUM 
    MOV AH, 09h 
    INT 21h 
    JMP @PRINT

@SUB : 
    MOV AL, NUM1 
    CMP AL, NUM2 
    JG  @WITHOUTNEG 
    JMP @WITHNEG

@WITHNEG : 
    MOV AL, NUM2 
    SUB AL, NUM1 
    MOV RES, AL

    LEA DX, DIFF 
    MOV AH, 09h 
    INT 21h

    MOV OP, "-" 
    MOV DL, OP 
    MOV AH,02h 
    INT 21h 
    JMP @PRINT

@WITHOUTNEG : 
    MOV AL, NUM1 
    SUB AL, NUM2 
    MOV RES, AL

    LEA DX, DIFF 
    MOV AH, 09h 
    INT 21h 
    JMP @PRINT

@MULTIPLY : 
    MOV AL, NUM1 
    IMUL NUM2 
    MOV RES, AL

    LEA DX, MULTI 
    MOV AH, 09h 
    INT 21h 
    JMP @PRINT

@DIVIDE : 
    XOR AX, AX 
    MOV AL, NUM1 
    IDIV NUM2 
    MOV RES, AL

    LEA DX, DIVI 
    MOV AH, 09h 
    INT 21h 
    JMP @PRINT

@MOD : 
    XOR AX, AX 
    MOV AL, NUM1 
    IDIV NUM2 
    MOV RES, AH

    LEA DX, MODULO 
    MOV AH, 09h 
    INT 21h 
    JMP @PRINT

@PRINT : 
    XOR AX, AX

    MOV AL, RES 
    MOV BL, 10 
    IDIV BL

    ADD AL, 0 
    MOV DL, AL 
    MOV AH,02h 
    INT 21h

    ADD AH, 0 
    MOV DL, AH 
    MOV AH,02h 
    INT 21h 
    JMP @EXIT

@EXIT : 
    MOV AH,4Ch 
    INT 21h

MAIN ENDP

;----------------------------------------------------------------

END MAIN
```

Comment: Can you give more information? What's happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Don't you normally need one assembler instruction per line?  It looks odd seeing 5 instructions on a single line as in some of this.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details on what do you wish to achieve with this code. Also `JMP @WITHNEG` on this line of code `@SUB : MOV AL, NUM1 CMP AL, NUM2 JG @WITHOUTNEG JMP @WITHNEG` is totally unnecessary as the next line is `@WITHNEG:` .According to line by line execution scheme, if JG is not met, the next line will be executed no matter what.

Another request is to write each instruction per line. This is hectic to read fluently and understand it along.

Also please use `code tags` when ever you are writing a code.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that your code is formatted, it is a bit easier to understand.

Let's fix one of your variables:

```
OPERAND DB 13,10, "ENTER OPERAND:,
```

Should be:

```
OPERAND DB 13,10, "ENTER OPERAND:", "$"
```

Next when you "get" a character, it is the ASCII code of the character so for single characters, to convert to a number you subtract 48 or "0", not 0 as your doing here:

```
; get first input 
MOV AH, 01h 
INT 21h 
SUB AL, 0 
MOV NUM1, AL
```

Should be:

```
; get first input 
MOV AH, 01h 
INT 21h 
SUB AL, "0" 
MOV NUM1, AL
```

See the difference?  Now, you can make the correction to your other input.

Next, you need an unconditional jump after your `OP` compares, otherwise it will go right to `@ADD` if the user did not enter a correct operator.

```
CMP OP, "%" 
JE  @MOD
jmp @EXIT   ; <----- added
```

Your `@MOD` code does not need a `JMP @PRINT` since it will "fall through" to your print routine anyways, same goes for the `JMP @EXIT` at the end of your print routine.

```
@PRINT : 

XOR AX, AX

MOV AL, RES 
MOV BL, 10 
IDIV BL

ADD AL, "0" 
MOV DL, AL 
MOV AH,02h 
INT 21h

ADD AH, 0 
MOV DL, AH 
MOV AH,02h 
INT 21h 
JMP @EXIT
```

Not really sure why you do:

```
MOV BL, 10 
IDIV BL
```

It is not needed.
Now, to convert the "number" back to its ASCII character, you reverse what you did for the input - add 48 or "0"

```
@PRINT : 
    XOR AX, AX

    MOV AL, RES 
    ADD AL, "0" 
    MOV DL, AL 
    MOV AH,02h 
    INT 21h

@EXIT : 
    MOV AH,4Ch 
    INT 21h
```

I must question why you are writing code in all CAPS?!?!  It makes code so much harder to read.  You should also check to see if the entered operator is one of the allowed.

Also, this code is fine for numbers less than or equal to 9, anything greater, you will need different code to convert to ASCII.